# Windows 8.1 VPN connection using Authentification Certificate

Tags: authentication, certificate, windows-8.1, vpn

With Cisco VPN Client, I can connect to a host through an IPsec/UDP connection by passing an Authentication Certificate (.p12) without username, password.

Are there some equivalent functions in Win 8.1 VPN Connection?
How to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good at VPN things, so I came back to VPN client.

Since Cisco VPN client doesn't support Windows 8 anymore, so I installed SonicWALL Global VPN **before** installing Cisco VPN Client 5.07. All we have to do is creat a new connection to your host server on SonicWall before using Cisco VPN Client.

Dell SonicWall:
http://help.mysonicwall.com/Applications/vpnclient/

@ I tried this solution with DNE Citrix before but it didn't work for me. Anyway I quote it here: http://www.gleescape.com/posts/2917

Have fun.